# How to hide all divs of same class using onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see by running the snippet 1 div isn't hiding , I'm a newbie so I don't know what to do? Can someone explain what's wrong? I can't figure it out.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("jobs");
function openandcloseavjobs() {


  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#jobs{
  height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:orange; 
    margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="openandcloseavjobs()">Average Pay</button>

<div id="jobs">

        <h3>job 1</h3>
</div>    

<div id="jobs">

        <h3>job 2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have  duplicate ids, they must be unique.

Comment: like @FluffyKitten said id's need to be unique. You need to use `class` if you want to select multiple elements

Comment: `id` != `class`

Comment: Oh yea sorry i know that , I meant id , let me try your method

Comment: by adding class , the function doesn't even run

Comment: Would you mind [accepting my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the grey checkmark in my answer if i have helped you! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `class` and use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method to get all `element` with same class name `.jobs` using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function to loop through all the elements and then use `display` `none` or `block` on all `found` element with that class name.

Also, where possible do **not** use `inline events` like `onClick` etc use `addEventListener` with a `click` instead.

**Live Demo:**

```js
var getEl = document.querySelectorAll(".jobs"); //get all element .jobs
var btn = document.querySelector("#getAvg"); //get the btn

//Button click function
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  getEl.forEach(function(item) { //forEach elements
    if (item.style.display === "none") {
      item.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      item.style.display = "none";
    }
  })
}, false);
```

```css
.jobs {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="getAvg">Average Pay</button>

<div class="jobs">

  <h3>job 1</h3>
</div>

<div class="jobs">

  <h3>job 2</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow , I love this community so help , Thank you so much i appreciate it a lot

Comment: @SilverNatureMusic Happy to help - Thanks

Comment: AlwaysHelping. Nice answer, but there is a sentence which is a bit misleading. You do not necessarily need to call querySelectorAll. You can also call getElementsByClassName, for example. See my answer. Nevertheless, besides this, your answer is correct. I upvoted it.

Comment: @LajosArpad querySelelectorAll and getElementbyClassName. Serve the same purpose. I am not sure how that can  be misleading to you ? May be you can read more on that in MDN.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping it is not misleading to me, because I am an experienced developer. It is misleading to novices. Since this is a question asked by a novice, telling him/her that "You need to use a class and use querySelectorAll method to get all element with same class name" suggests that he/she will HAVE to use querySelectorAll, that is, there is no alternative. Actually, there are alternative methods one may choose from, including, but not limited to querySelectorAll.

Comment: So, instead of the misleading "You need to use a class and use querySelectorAll method to get all element with same class name" you could rephrase it to "You need to use a class and you can use querySelectorAll method to get all element with same class name". That would keep the meaning you have meant to the statement and would no longer be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function getElementById only finds 1 element as the name suggests.

You should try with class names so change the  to  and use the function getElementsByClassName("example").

Comment: by class name the function doesn't even run

Comment: It's because the `getElementsByClassName("jobs")` returns a list of those selected elements. You must further loop through that list and then perform your `style.display` updates.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id` (identifier, which, by definition should be unique) to select multiple elements. To achieve what you want, use a class

```js
var X = document.getElementsByClassName("jobs");
function openandcloseavjobs() {

  for (let x of X) {
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.jobs{
  height: 100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:orange; 
    margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="openandcloseavjobs()">Average Pay</button>

<div class="jobs">

        <h3>job 1</h3>
</div>    

<div class="jobs">

        <h3>job 2</h3>
</div>
```